# Error message [object Object]

Tags: excel, vba

this is my first question...

when running the below code from Excel vba i get the -
message from website [object Object]

can pls someone assit on finding solution for this

```
Sub SearchCont()

Dim objIE1 As Object
Set objIE1 = CreateObject("INTERNETEXPLORER.APPLICATION")
objIE1.navigate 
("http://www.israports.co.il/he/TaskYam/Pages/ContainerStatus.aspx")
objIE1.Visible = True
Do
DoEvents
Loop Until objIE1.readyState = 4
objIE1.document.getElementById("ports").Value = "2"
Do
DoEvents
Loop Until objIE1.readyState = 4
objIE1.document.getElementById("number").Value = "ADMU4111809"
Dim aaa As HTMLInputElement
For Each aaa In objIE1.document.getElementsByTagName("input")
If aaa.Value = "חפש" Then Exit For
    Next
aaa.Click

End Sub
```

thanks :)

Comment: The error message is just "[object Object]"?  Not sure if it's related, but what if none of the elements have a value of "חפש"? aaa will be Nothing and aaa.Click will fail.

Comment: there is element with value "חפש" and when the code do "click" i get the error.. nothing nore than [object Object] :(

Comment: Try `aaa.innerText` and it is normal to get that as output or [HtmlLiObject]. You have to program the DOM parsing correctly to extract what you want.